# opencv copy data from a *Mat to a Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have two `cv::Mat` objects:

```
cv::Mat *frameLeftRemap;
cv::Mat frameLeft2;
```

Data streams into *frameLeftRemap from a camera. I need to copy the data to frameLeft2, then delete frameLeftRemap, to avoid the frame artifacts I am seeing. (This was suggested by the camera manufacturer support desk.)

the function is:

```
  void ProcessImageLeft(AVT::VmbAPI::FramePtr pFrame)
    {
        VmbUchar_t *pBuffer;
        VmbUint32_t FrameWidth;
        VmbUint32_t FrameHeight;


        //prepare frame information:
        pFrame->GetWidth(FrameWidth);
        pFrame->GetHeight(FrameHeight);
        pFrame->GetImage(pBuffer);
        //edited
        Mat1b imageL(FrameHeight, FrameWidth, (uchar*)pBuffer);

        cv::remap(imageL, *frameLeftRemap, mx1, my1, cv::INTER_LINEAR);

        frameLeft2 = frameLeftRemap->clone(); 

        //frameLeftRemap->copyTo(frameLeft2);


        cv::imshow("right", frameLeft2);
        cv::waitKey(1);
        delete frameLeftRemap;


    }
```

both copyTo and clone give an error:

```
this is nullPtr. read access violation
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. As already pointed out, this should work correctly if your images are still valid. Also, it's usually a bad idea to use `Mat*`, since you're likely to break internal reference counting (as you're probably doing here)

Comment: Why are you even using `IplImage`? Please avoid obsolete C api. Please refactor this code to use only `Mat`. The error would probably be solved already

Comment: That part is code from the camera manufacturer. How would I go about turning *pBuffer straight into a Mat? Thanks.

Comment: `Mat1b m(rows, cols, (uchar*)buffer, step)`

Comment: Mat1b copyimageL(FrameWidth, FrameHeight, (uchar*)pBuffer, CV_AUTO_STEP);  Works, but when i use cv::imshow("left",copyimageL); it breaks with the error: Grey was 0x8844D6F9. Do I need to assign a var for 'step'?

Comment: What's `Grey`? Please post also the updated snippet. If `step` is equal to `cols`, you don't need to specify it

Comment: also, you should swap `FrameWidth` and `FrameHeight`: `Mat1b copyimageL(FrameHeight, FrameWidth, (uchar*)pBuffer);`

Comment: Ah ok that works, thanks. I still see the original problem though!

Comment: Have you initialized `frameLeftRemap`? `Mat* frameLeftRemap = new Mat();`?

Comment: slight improvement, that will bring the images up, then crash with 'Access violation reading location'

Comment: 1. *never* use pointers to cv::Mat. it's a smartpointer already, and you're defeating it's purpose. 2. you `delete frameLeftRemap;` inside your function, but we don't see the creation. what happens, if you call `ProcessImageLeft` twice ?

Comment: AH, I create it OUTSIDE the function. That would explain the nullPtr error, right? As I delete it, then on the next loop, try to use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`frameL= frameLeftRemap->clone();` should work correctly. It seems you have problem in `frameL`. Try to show it using `cv::imshow` or `cv::imwrite` to make sure it was corrupted before cloning it. Then fix the original problem. If you posted code, we would help you more.